# Element is getting ui-resizable but not ui-resizable-handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-resizable

I have a list of elements that I am trying to add jQuery UIs resizable functionality to after loading them and they are getting the class **ui-resizable**, but the div with the class **ui-resizable-handle** is not being added.

First I start with (and before you ask, yes I have peeled away some code that is not required in the example)...

```
function setElementsAsResizable(elements, isResizable) {
    elements.each(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        if (element.is(':data(ui-resizable)'))
            element.resizable("destroy");
        if (isResizable)
            element.addClass("resizable");
        }
        else {
            if (element.hasClass("resizable"))
                element.removeClass("resizable");
        }
    });
}
```

This is is so I start with a clean slate, just in case the elements are no longer resizable. After this I create the elements.

```
function createResizableElements(row) {
    var element = row.children(".element.resizable");
    element.resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        containment: 'parent',
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).parent().on('resize', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        },
        start: function (event, ui) {...},
        resize: function (event, ui) {...},
        stop: function (event, ui) {...}
    });
```

So all of my elements have now been bestowed with the **ui-resizable**, but not all of them have have not received the div **ui-resizable-handle** which renders the whole thing unusable. The elements are also sortable (which works) and when I drag and drop them they go through the same process, but have now been given **ui-resizable-handle**.

So in short, does anyone know how an element can be set as ui-resizable, but *not* get the handle that is needed to actually resize?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is embarrassing. Apparently, this is due to a bug in jQueryUI and the answer on how to fix that exists here:

[How do I destroy a jquery resizable without destroying child resizables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462382/how-do-i-destroy-a-jquery-resizable-without-destroying-child-resizables)

Short summation: You call destroy on an element it will remove that elements jQueryUI behaviour and remove the handle for all of that element's children that happen to have one.

I have to stop finding library bugs while coding with jQueryUI that are hard to search for.